# What does it mean - "подняться на крыло"

Tags: выражения, значения

[Here is](http://www.gazeta.ru/politics/news/2012/10/10/n_2565605.shtml) a quote from today news:

> "На прошлой неделе выпал первый снег, и серые журавли, обитающие на
>   Белом озере, сразу *поднялись на крыло и улетели*", - рассказал
>   представитель регионального управления Росприроднадзора, добавив, что
>   птенцы стерхов не смогли полететь вместе с ними, так как, скорее
>   всего, не успели полностью адаптироваться.

My question is - what exactly does "подняться на крыло" mean and how does it differ from "улетели"? Is it an exact synonym for "взлететь" or there are some shifts in connotation/denotaion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meaning of `подняться на крыло` is closer to `взлететь` (to take off) than to `улететь` (to fly away). It makes sense to replace `взлететь` with `подняться на крыло` in the phrase that you quoted to avoid perception of repetition: `сразу взлетели и улетели` sounds repetitive, while `сразу поднялись на крыло и улетели` does not.

Answer (score 11):

подняться на крыло has two meanings, according to Большой словарь русских поговорок from [Academic](http://dic.academic.ru). The first one is "взлететь" (and here it is equivalent to "встать на крыло"), the second one is "начать летать" (about nestlings).

Examples from Russian National Corpus:

1. meaning:
   Думал, что после длительного заточения птица, ослабев, не сможет взлететь, однако голубь на удивление бодро поднялся на крыло и упорхнул в синюю даль неба…
2. meaning:
   Дома я внимательно осмотрел птенца, никаких видимых повреждений не обнаружил, и это вселило в меня надежду, что скоро он сможет подняться на крыло.

In your example it means "взлететь".

Answer (score 6):

From here, stripped:  http://glossword.info/index.php/term/,6ea3ac6f59585f926e6b6a9a5aa4a459955c6bac6bb0a653535d54aa5db09a585957536862a9a66d6170986f69585aafaaac989f62a1ac6d616a98a75468a271695256.xhtml#

> ВСТАВАТЬ НА КРЫЛО. ВСТАТЬ НА КРЫЛО. 
>   Начинать летать. О птенцах.

i.e. 'to learn how to fly'. I will not be surprised, if it will be applied to birds temporary unable to fly, for example, because of feathers changing.

> Взлетать.

i.e. 'to fly up'

> Экспрес. Приобретать самостоятельность, независимость от других.

i.e. 'to become self-sufficient' (loose translation)

Answer (score 6):

Подняться на крыло - приобрести способность летать. Если птица поднялась на крыло - птенец уже научился летать. Самолет поднялся на крыло - новая конструкция самолета разработана до той стадии, что пробный образец самолета уже летает.

Answer (score 2):

I would say here is doesn't mean exactly just "take off/fly up", but rather underlines that they "took off" after spending some time settled on the sea. It doesn't mean that all this time they didn't fly, but they always were somewhere around.

Answer (score -1):

It's an idiom that corresponds to "take wing" in English.

Comment: Welcome to Russian.SE.  We prefer expanded answers over short one-liners.  Also, in this particular case, I believe you are misunderstanding the meaning of "take wing" idiom in English, which means "fly off" or "take off" - definitely different from the meaning of Russian "подняться на крыло".